# What is the proper control for updating a combobox

Tags: combobox, wxpython

Can someone give me some direction as to the proper control to use to update the items in a combobox if a certain item is selected in another combobox? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update a list in a combobox, use it's SetItems(myNewList) method. I would keep a dictionary of the various lists you need and use that to populate the second combobox based on the selection in the first.

Comment: Nice. I did not know about it.

Comment: me either ... is there such thing as an exhaustive wxPython manual!

Comment: Not really, although you can learn a lot from Robin Dunn's book and Precord's Cookbook. I learn a lot from reading and helping on the wxPython mailing list.